# Angular 9 ngx tabs - dynamic tabs not visible until mouse clic

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a component where I am trying to create dynamic tabs and it appears that I am. However, the dynamic tabs are not visible until I click on the component. I am not sure what the issue is. The data is a behavior subject which I subscribe to. I get the data when the subject changes, however the  dynamcic tabs are not displayed until I click on the component.

Here is my code..

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe((message) => {
        this.companyData = message;

        console.log(
            'Companies returned = ' + JSON.stringify(this.companyData)
        );

        // remove previous tabs
        this.removeAll();

        let count = 0;
        for (const company of this.companyData) {
            this.addNewTab(
                company.companyName,
                company.sicDesciption,
                count === 0 ? true : false
            );
            count++;
        }
    });
}

ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.tabs.length > 1) {
        //this.searchResultTabs.tabs[0].elementRef. = false;
        //this.removeTabHandler(this.tabs[0]);
        this.selectTab(0);
    }
}

addNewTab(
    companyName: string,
    description: string,
    activate: boolean
): void {
    const newTabIndex = this.tabs.length + 1;
    this.tabs.push({
        title: companyName,
        content: description,
        disabled: false,
        removable: true,
        active: activate
    });
}
```

```html
<div (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
    <div class="tab-panel">
        <tabset id="TEST" class="search-tabset" #searchResultTabs>
            <tab heading="Static tab experiment">Blah blau</tab>
            <tab
                *ngFor="let t of tabs"
                [heading]="t.title"
                [active]="t.active"
                (deselect)="t.active = false"
                [disabled]="t.disabled"
                [removable]="t.removable"
                (removed)="removeTabHandler(t)"
                [customClass]="t.customClass"
            >
                {{ t?.content }}
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Have you made any changes to the ChangeDetection setting on the module?

Comment: It was the change detection logic. Thanks